# Accessing to the MovieClip before the target

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm very new in AS3 programming,

#### Problem Example

onStage I have image_contenter as MovieClip.

> image_contenter_mc ----Stage
>
> movieClip1      ----Inside image_contenter_mc
>
> movieClip2      ----Inside movieClip1
>
> movieClip3      ----Inside movieClip2
>
> movieClip4      ----Inside movieClip3

now  I try to access to the movieClip3 by using

> event.target.name

it return movieClip4 and

> event.currentTarget

also not work. So how can I access the movieClip3 and movieClip2

> event.(target-1).name --i think it will error when i use this also.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "parent" property on the target to get its parent, assuming the target is a DisplayObject type of object (which in this case it is).

```
// cast the target to a DisplayObject (since we want to treat it as a DisplayObject object)
var current:DisplayObject = (DisplayObject) (event.target);

// this would lead to the parent of the display object
// movieclip 3 is the parent of movieclip 4
// movieclip 2 is the parent of movieclip 3
// and so on
trace(current.parent);
```

DisplayObject - Adobe ActionScript® 3 (AS3 ) API Reference
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent

Comment: thak you I help me a lot :D